# LINQ - Sort by StartsWith and then Contains (AutoComplete)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm implementing a `autocomplete` feature where I need to filter SQL table based on User Input.

So, Requirement is to filter for the records where it should begin(`sort`) the results with `StartsWith` and then `Contains`.

Sample Data:

Dotnet Developer
Azure Administrator
Microsoft Azure
Azure DevOps
UX Developer
IOT Azure

If I start typing **Azu**, then it should show the results in the below order.

**Azu**re Administrator
**Azu**re DevOps
Microsoft **Azu**re
IOT **Azu**re

which means, we are looking for the results which `startswith` logic and then `contains` logic.

Currently, I have tried two approaches but those didn't work.

First Approach:

```
dbContext.dbTable.Select(h => h.FieldName.ToLowerInvariant()).Where(e => e.Contains(text)).OrderBy(s => s).Distinct().Take(count).ToList();
```

Second Approach:

```
dbContext.dbTable.Where(e => e.FieldName.Contains(text)).OrderBy(h => h.FieldName.IndexOf(text)).ThenBy(c => c.FieldName.Length).Select(p => p.FieldName).Distinct().Take(count).ToList();
```

Can anyone please guide me if this can be possible?

Comment: FYI, this pattern is named *type ahead*. May help you find other solutions :). But can you please elaborate on "didn't work". What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is the requirements or the understanding of the requirements.

**Filter operation:**
Reduce(=filter) the results based on a boolean expresssion where:
`true`  ==> show the result
`false` ==> **don't** show.
It is achieved in linq, by the Where(...) clause.

In your case, the requirement is to **Filter** by the results that contain `text`.

```c
.Where(e => e.Contains(text))
```

**Sort Operation:**
Given a list of results, decide on the order of them.
Your requirement is to see the values that Start by `text` first.
In other words, to **Sort** by this rule.

`String.StartsWith` returns a boolean.
Running linq's `OrderBy` on booleans, orders them by `false` and then by `true`.
This is because OrderBy default sorting is ascending, and `false` counts as "smaller" than `true`. (reasonable decision)

So, knowing this, you can achieve what you want by running

```
.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartsWith(text))
```

Full Logic:

```
dbContext.dbTable
         .Select(h => h.FieldName.ToLowerInvariant())
         .Where(e => e.Contains(text)) // filter
         .Distinct() // more filtering
         .OrderByDescending(s => s.StartsWith(text)) // sort 
         .Take(count)
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dbContext
  .dbTable
  .Where(x => x.FieldName.Contains(text))
  .Distinct()
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.FieldName.StartsWith(text))
  .Take(count);
```

1. Filter only records that contain the search criteria (`.Where(x => x.FieldName.Contains(text))`)
2. Sort those so that ones that begin with the search criteria are first (`.OrderByDescending(x => x.FieldName.StartsWith(text))`)

Comment: You had it, but the OrderBy was the wrong way around. Either `.OrderBy(x => x.FieldName.StartsWith(text) ? 0 : 1)` or `.OrderByDescending(...)` would have been it. Upvoting because it was a concise explanation. (Had to try it out to see)  One last consideration is that this assumes the database is using CI (Case insensitive) collation. If CS, add ToLower/ToUpper for comparisons.

Comment: Good catch Steve. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following

```
    dbContext.dbTable.Where(e => e.FieldName.Contains(text)).OrderBy(h => h.FieldName.ToLower().StartsWith(searchString.ToLower()) ? 0 : 1)
.ThenBy(c => c.FieldName.ToLower().Contains("order")).Select(p => p.FieldName).Distinct().Take(count).ToList();
```